# Deadlock in queue-like table, with SqlDependency mixed in

Tags: sql-server, sqldependency

I have a table that is used as a simple change log; rows need to be read from it in the same order they were written. The table looks like this :

```
create table PublishedEvent (
    PublishedEventId int identity not null,
    EntityGuid uniqueidentifier null,
    EntityId int null,
    EventName nvarchar(100) not null,
    Operation nvarchar(10) not null,
    Timestamp datetimeoffset not null default(sysdatetimeoffset()),
    primary key (PublishedEventId)
);
```

The table is written to from within triggers similar to this one :

```
create trigger Appointment_Insert on Appointment after insert as 
begin
    insert into PublishedEvent (EntityName, EntityId, Operation) 
        select 'Appointment', i.AppointmentId, 'insert' from inserted i
end
```

There are many such triggers, so that there are effectively many writers.

In the application code, the PublishedEvent table is read via an instance of SqlDependency. I use SqlDependency because I want to avoid polling the database, and at the same time I need to react quickly when new rows arrive.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var tr = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("select PublishedEventId, EventName, EntityGuid, EntityId, Operation, Timestamp from dbo.PublishedEvent order by PublishedEventId", conn, tr);

        var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

        dependency.OnChange += HandleDependencyChange;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Access to the SqlDependency is serialized, such that there can only be one outstanding query at a time. The application reads the PublishedEvent rows returned by the query, and processes them. Of course, it is also hooked up to the SqlDependency's OnChange event so the cycle can begin anew.

Once the application is done processing the PublishedEvent rows, it deletes them :

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var tr = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from pe from PublishedEvent pe inner join @EventIds ei on ei.Id = pe.PublishedEventId", tr.Connection, tr);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventIds", ...));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

*Note: @EventIds is a table-valued parameter containing the PublishedEventId column of the previously-read PublishedEvent rows.*

Now, my problem is that I sometimes get deadlocks in the database. SQL Profiler tells me that the deadlocks occur between inserts to the Appointment table (presumably inserts in PublishedEvent from Foo's trigger is the true culprit) and deletes to the PublishedEvent table.
I have looked at relevant articles on the web, such as [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), but none seem to have the same constraints as I.

Is there a way of avoiding deadlocks, and at the same time have a solution allowing for multiple writers, and single reader that uses SqlDependency?

**Edit** : At the request of @usr, here is a sample deadlock graph. As you will see, the SQL is bit more complicated than was stated in the question, although I don't think my elisions change anything w.r.t. my problem.

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process5989b88">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process5989b88" taskpriority="0" logused="864" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594076397568 (7860bcaa51f1)" waittime="717" ownerId="8200442" transactionname="DeletePublishedEvents" lasttranstarted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.067" XDES="0x8004b950" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="2" kpid="9560" status="suspended" spid="56" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.070" lastbatchcompleted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.067" clientapp="dev-MobileMed Noyau" hostname="PLALONDEW8" hostpid="22392" loginname="PLALONDEW8\dev-MM$Core" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="8200442" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="82" sqlhandle="0x02000000fac6ff387b191d62a29fa17565e4e54bcc8aa7f5">
delete from pe from PublishedEvent pe inner join @EventIds ei on ei.Id = pe.PublishedEventId     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@EventIds [dbo].[IntTableType] READONLY)delete from pe from PublishedEvent pe inner join @EventIds ei on ei.Id = pe.PublishedEventId    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process59bddc8" taskpriority="0" logused="162844" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594076397568 (49d0d2cdfe43)" waittime="715" ownerId="8200412" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.060" XDES="0x805d1950" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="4" kpid="18004" status="suspended" spid="70" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.067" lastbatchcompleted="2014-11-08T12:32:54.067" clientapp="dev-MMImporter" hostname="PLALONDEW8" hostpid="22012" loginname="PLALONDEW8\dev-MM$Core" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="8200412" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="dev-DmeDB.dbo.ScheduleSlot_InsertUpdate" line="19" stmtstart="1246" stmtend="2066" sqlhandle="0x03000500a888b73a4c40d900dca300000000000000000000">
insert into PublishedEvent (EventName, EntityId, Operation) 
                        select &apos;ScheduleSlot&apos;, i.ScheduleSlotId, 
                            case
                                when i.IsDeleted = 1 then &apos;softdelete&apos;
                                when d.ScheduleSlotId is null then &apos;insert&apos;
                                else &apos;update&apos;
                            end
                            from inserted i
                                left join deleted d on i.ScheduleSlotId = d.ScheduleSlotId;     </frame>
     <frame procname="dev-DmeDB.medicoadmin.PLAGEHORAIRERV_AIU_REPL" line="10" stmtstart="548" stmtend="1786" sqlhandle="0x03000500bbf3ef51aabcd900dca300000000000000000000">
with cte (ScheduleSlotId, AppointmentTypeId, AppointmentId) as
    (
        select ss.ScheduleSlotId, at.AppointmentTypeId, a.AppointmentId
            from inserted i
                inner join dbo.ScheduleSlot ss on ss.MedicoAdminId = i.ID_PLAGEHORAIRE
                left join AppointmentType at on at.MedicoAdminId = i.ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS
                left join Appointment a on a.MedicoAdminId = i.ID_RENDEZVOUS
    )
    merge dbo.ScheduleSlot as target
        using cte as source on (target.ScheduleSlotId = source.ScheduleSlotId)
        when matched then
            update set
                AppointmentTypeId = source.AppointmentTypeId,
                AppointmentId     = source.AppointmentId;     </frame>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="150" sqlhandle="0x02000000938c652d03c75d708e1fa976f91c4da900714d0c">
INSERT INTO [medicoadmin].PLAGEHORAIRERV (ID_PLAGEHORAIRE, ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS, ID_RENDEZVOUS) VALUES (@ID_PLAGEHORAIRE, @ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS, @ID_RENDEZVOUS);     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@ID_PLAGEHORAIRE int,@ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS int,@ID_RENDEZVOUS nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO [medicoadmin].PLAGEHORAIRERV (ID_PLAGEHORAIRE, ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS, ID_RENDEZVOUS) VALUES (@ID_PLAGEHORAIRE, @ID_TYPERENDEZVOUS, @ID_RENDEZVOUS);    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594076397568" dbid="5" objectname="dev-DmeDB.sys.query_notification_155199653" indexname="cidx" id="lock88780d00" mode="RangeX-X" associatedObjectId="72057594076397568">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process59bddc8" mode="RangeX-X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process5989b88" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594076397568" dbid="5" objectname="dev-DmeDB.sys.query_notification_155199653" indexname="cidx" id="lock8f111a80" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594076397568">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process5989b88" mode="RangeS-U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process59bddc8" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: What indexes are on the queue table? If each key is inserted and deleted exactly once there can be no deadlocks. There is something going on that is not apparent from the question. How many inserts and deletes are there in one transaction at most? Maybe lock escalation starting at 5000 locks.

Comment: @usr There are no additional indexes. All interactions with the table are shown in the question : the inserts, the deletes, and the reads via SqlDependency.

Comment: OK. Post the deadlock graph as XML.

Comment: @usr I have edited the question to include the deadlock graph.

Comment: Interesting case. You are deadlocking on internal query notification tables. Post the actual query plans for an insert and a delete as XML. Can you find out the schema of the internal table by querying the system metadata tables?; Note, that your deletes fire the notification causing another empty round of processing. You might want to avoid that by setting the notification with a filter like `id > lastProcessedID`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement an actual queue? Since you're already using SQL Dependency, that tells me that you're on a version of SQL Server that has Service Broker (which is the underpinning technology in SQL Server that implements SQL Dependency). Your trigger would insert a message into a SB queue and you'd use what is called "external activation" to tell your application that there are messages in the queue to go pick up. The advantage is that queues were designed for this sort of thing. There is an inherent ordering to the messages in the queue (first in, first out); all you have to do is ask for the next one. There's no way from the SB side to serialize read access, but if you ever only have one reader, that should be good enough.

I don't know the specifics of your use case, but if your application is processing events and then doing something on the database side as a result, consider "internal activation" instead. This is when you write a stored procedure to deal with messages and that procedure gets called by the database engine automatically when messages arrive on the queue. In this case, you can say how many simultaneous readers you want to have (in your case, one), though that still doesn't prevent another process from reading a message off the queue outside of the internal activation process.

Comment: I don't interact with Service Broker directly because it seems a lot more complex than going through SqlDependency. Although I'm starting to think I'll have no choice ...

Comment: There are some moving parts to be sure. But it's not as bad as all that, I assure you.